# Data Not displaying in ionic and angular List

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am new to ionic and angular. was trying to create a list with json data

```
{"menu":[{"name":"Mixed Veg Wrap","image":"mix-veg-wrap.jpg","category":"WRAPS, Light Bites","spice_meter":"1","description":"Spicy mixed vegetables :)","rating":"3","price":"35","is_veg":"yes"},{"name":"Egg Wrap","image":"egg-wraps.jpg","category":"WRAPS, Light Bites","spice_meter":"0","description":"Double egg coating with Onion and Sauces!","rating":"4.9","price":"36","is_veg":"no"},{"name":"Cheese Melt Paneer","image":"cmp.jpg","category":"WRAPS, Special","spice_meter":"0","description":"Paneer in Reshmi Masala with melted Cheese","rating":"4.5","price":"91","is_veg":"yes"},{"name":"Prawns Tikka","image":"prawan.jpg","category":"WRAPS, Special","spice_meter":"1","description":"Prawns in spicy tikka masala.","rating":"3.5","price":"110","is_veg":"no"}
```

Here is my controller the app.js

```
// Ionic Starter App

// angular.module is a global place for creating, registering and retrieving Angular modules
// 'starter' is the name of this angular module example (also set in a <body> attribute in index.html)
// the 2nd parameter is an array of 'requires'
angular.module('starter', ['ionic'])

.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
    // for form inputs)
    if(window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
    }
    if(window.StatusBar) {
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
    }
  });
}).controller('ListController', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
    $http.get('js/data.json').success(function(data) {
      $scope.menu = data;  
    });
}]);
```

Here is my index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
    <title></title>

    <link href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- IF using Sass (run gulp sass first), then uncomment below and remove the CSS includes above
    <link href="css/ionic.app.css" rel="stylesheet">
    -->

    <!-- ionic/angularjs js -->
    <script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>

    <!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) -->
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>

    <!-- your app's js -->
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-app="starter">
    <ion-pane>
      <ion-header-bar class="bar-dark">
        <h2 class="title">Artist List</h2>
      </ion-header-bar>
      <div class="bar bar-subheader 
        item-input-inset bar-light">
        <label class="item-input-wrapper">
          <i class="icon ion-search placeholder-icon"></i>
          <input type="search" placeholder="Search">
        </label>
      </div>
      <ion-content ng-controller="ListController" 
        class="has-subheader">
        <ion-list>
          <ion-item ng-repeat='item in menu'
          class="item-text-wrap">
          <h2>{{item.name}}</h2>
            <img ng-src="img/{{item.image}}" />
            <h3>{{item.category}}</h3>
            <h3>{{item.spice_meter}}</h3>
            <h3>{{item.description}}</h3>
            <h3>{{item.rating}}</h3>
            <h3>{{item.price}}</h3>
            <h3>{{item.is_veg}}</h3>
          </ion-item>
        </ion-list>
      </ion-content>
    </ion-pane>
  </body>
</html>
```

Nut the resultant o/p is blank list
i checked the console which shows

> ionic.bundle.js:17752 XHR finished loading: GET
>   "http://192.168.1.201:8100/js/data.json".(anonymous function) @
>   ionic.bundle.js:17752sendReq @ ionic.bundle.js:17553serverRequest @
>   ionic.bundle.js:17269processQueue @ ionic.bundle.js:21114(anonymous
>   function) @ ionic.bundle.js:21130Scope.$eval @
>   ionic.bundle.js:22326Scope.$digest @ ionic.bundle.js:22142Scope.$apply
>   @ ionic.bundle.js:22431bootstrapApply @ ionic.bundle.js:9373invoke @
>   ionic.bundle.js:12110doBootstrap @ ionic.bundle.js:9371bootstrap @
>   ionic.bundle.js:9391angularInit @ ionic.bundle.js:9285(anonymous
>   function) @ ionic.bundle.js:34050trigger @
>   ionic.bundle.js:10669eventHandler @ ionic.bundle.js:10939

Please help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that the path you are seeing in browser console `http://192.168.1.201:8100/js/data.json` is correct.

Then while assigning menu use `data.menu` instead of just `data`

```
.controller('ListController', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
    $http.get('js/data.json').success(function(data) {
      $scope.menu = data.menu;  //assigning menu
    });
}]);
```

Comment: Thank u some much.. for quick help.. really helped!!